# unwanted jquery-ui-1.8.9.custom.css showing up

Tags: html, css, jquery-ui-tabs

I'm trying to create some simple tabs to better organize content. When the code is ran from my desktop it works fine, however when it is placed in Percussion's CMS the styling is off. While using Chrome's inspect element tool I found that there is a jquery-ui-1.8.9.custom.css file that is affecting my styling. I haven't linked to this file in in the header section of my code. Any thoughts on how and why this phantom css file is showing up when ran in Percussion? And if so, how do I prevent this file from affecting my styling. Here's a copy of my code in case someone needs it.

```css
/* Default tab style */

.tabs {
 position: relative;
 overflow: hidden;
 margin: 0 auto;
 width: 100%;
 font-weight: 300;
 font-size: 1.25em;
}

/* Nav */
.tabs nav {
 text-align: center;
}

.tabs nav ul {
 position: relative;
 display: -ms-flexbox;
 display: -webkit-flex;
 display: -moz-flex;
 display: -ms-flex;
 display: flex;
 margin: 0 auto;
 padding: 0;
 max-width: 1200px;
 list-style: none;
 -ms-box-orient: horizontal;
 -ms-box-pack: center;
 -webkit-flex-flow: row wrap;
 -moz-flex-flow: row wrap;
 -ms-flex-flow: row wrap;
 flex-flow: row wrap;
 -webkit-justify-content: center;
 -moz-justify-content: center;
 -ms-justify-content: center;
 justify-content: center;
}

.tabs nav ul li {
 position: relative;
 z-index: 1;
 display: block;
 margin: 0;
 text-align: center;
 -webkit-flex: 1;
 -moz-flex: 1;
 -ms-flex: 1;
 flex: 1;
}

.tabs nav a {
 position: relative;
 display: block;
 overflow: hidden;
 text-overflow: ellipsis;
 white-space: nowrap;
 line-height: 2.5;
 text-decoration: none;
}

.tabs nav a span {
 vertical-align: middle;
 font-size: 0.75em;
}

.tabs nav li.tab-current a {
 color: #74777e;
}

.tabs nav a:focus {
 outline: none !important;
}

/* Icons */
.icon::before {
 z-index: 10;
 display: inline-block;
 margin: 0 0.4em 0 0;
 vertical-align: middle;
 text-transform: none;
 font-weight: normal;
 font-variant: normal;
 font-size: 1.3em;
 font-family: 'stroke7pixeden';
 line-height: 1;
 speak: none;
 -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
 -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
 -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
}
.icon-upload::before {
 content: "\e68a";
}
.icon-tools::before {
 content: "\e60a";
}
.icon-plane::before {
 content: "\e625";
}
.icon-joy::before {
 content: "\e6a4";
}
.icon-plug::before {
 content: "\e69a";
}
.icon-home::before {
 content: "\e648";
}
.icon-gift::before {
 content: "\e652";
}
.icon-display::before {
 content: "\e65e";
}
.icon-date::before {
 content: "\e660";
}
.icon-config::before {
 content: "\e666";
}
.icon-coffee::before {
 content: "\e669";
}
.icon-camera::before {
 content: "\e66f";
}
.icon-box::before {
 content: "\e674";
}

/* Content */
.content-wrap {
 position: relative;
}

.content-wrap section {
 display: none;
 margin: 0 auto;
 padding: 1em;
 max-width: 1200px;
 text-align: center;
}

.content-wrap section.content-current {
 display: block;
}

.content-wrap section p {
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0.75em 0;
 color: rgba(40,44,42,0.05);
 font-weight: 900;
 font-size: 4em;
 line-height: 1;
}

/* Fallback */
.no-js .content-wrap section {
 display: block;
 padding-bottom: 2em;
 border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(255,255,255,0.6);
}

.no-flexbox nav ul {
 display: block;
}

.no-flexbox nav ul li {
 min-width: 15%;
 display: inline-block;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 58em) {
 .tabs nav a.icon span {
  display: none;
 }
 .tabs nav a:before {
  margin-right: 0;
 }
}

/* Individual tab styles */

/*****************************/
/* Top Line */
/*****************************/
#tabs {
 border: 1px solid rgba(40,44,42,0.05);
 border-top: none;
}

.tabs-style-topline {
 max-width: 1200px;
}

.tabs-style-topline nav li {
 border: 1px solid rgba(40,44,42,0.1);
}

.tabs-style-topline nav li:not(:last-child) {
 border-right: none;
}

.tabs-style-topline nav li.ui-state-active {
 border-top: 3px solid #2CC185;
 border-bottom: none;
}
.tabs-style-topline nav li.ui-state-active a {
    background: #fff;
}
.tabs-style-topline nav a {
 padding: 0.75em 0 0.5em !important;
 background: rgba(40,44,42,0.05) !important;
 color: #258e76;
 line-height: 1;
 font-weight: bold !important;
 -webkit-transition: color 0.2s;
 transition: color 0.2s;
}


.tabs-style-topline nav a:hover {
 color: #2CC185;
}
.tabs-style-topline nav a:focus {
 color: #258e76;
}

.tabs-style-topline nav li.tab-current a {
 background: none;
 box-shadow: inset 0 3px 0 #2CC185;
 color: #2CC185;
}

.tabs-style-topline .icon::before {
 display: block;
 margin: 0;
}

#tabs-1, #tabs-2, #tabs-3, #tabs-4 {
 padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
 <!-- <link rel="stylesheet" href="jquery-ui.css"> -->
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="tabs.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="tabstyles.css" />

  <script>
  $(function() {
    $( "#tabs" ).tabs();
  });
  </script>
</head>
<body>
 
<div id="tabs" class="tabs tabs-style-topline">
  <nav>
    <ul style="background: transparent; border-top: none; border-left:none; border-right: none;">
      <li><a href="#tabs-1">Tab 1</a></li>
      <li><a href="#tabs-2">Tab 2</a></li>
      <li><a href="#tabs-3">Tab 3</a></li>
      <li><a href="#tabs-4">Tab 4</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
<div id="tabs-1" >
        <p><strong>Tab 1</strong><br>
    <br>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Praesent nec viverra nisi. Donec imperdiet justo arcu, quis ornare magna vehicula vel. Proin fringilla ultricies tellus eget tempus. Mauris vehicula malesuada velit at hendrerit. Pellentesque ac bibendum est, at dictum mi. Curabitur interdum lectus magna, et rhoncus enim vulputate auctor. Nunc eleifend pellentesque libero, et lacinia odio laoreet vitae. Maecenas fermentum sagittis ipsum ut vestibulum. Praesent varius nisi sed nisl ultrices cursus. Aenean risus lacus, ultricies at tincidunt nec, suscipit in diam. Quisque tincidunt sed mauris vitae sodales. Cras hendrerit, metus id sollicitudin ornare, ligula odio porttitor sem, sit amet tristique turpis ipsum in ipsum. Morbi volutpat purus a felis lacinia, ac scelerisque mi vulputate. Phasellus posuere dui sit amet tellus pharetra porta.</p>
  </div>
  <div id="tabs-2">
    <p><strong>Tab 2</strong><br>
    <br>
    In orci massa, imperdiet vel lacinia rutrum, egestas id eros. Integer ac sollicitudin odio. Vestibulum eget gravida tortor. Mauris fringilla dolor at ultricies sodales. Ut hendrerit ligula tempor, venenatis justo sed, luctus felis. Aenean dapibus, orci eu laoreet pretium, lectus diam rhoncus dolor, scelerisque convallis dui neque ut ligula. Duis convallis mauris sed tortor consequat cursus. Aenean dictum placerat mi vel tristique. Vestibulum ornare sem ut arcu posuere pretium. Sed nisi augue, consectetur vel mi vel, sodales hendrerit leo. Sed vulputate tempus est ac vehicula. Vestibulum in pharetra erat.</p>
  </div>
  <div id="tabs-3">
       <p><strong>Tab 3</strong><br>
    <br>In viverra nunc quis magna blandit sodales. Duis tempus molestie pharetra. Maecenas ipsum eros, lacinia vel tincidunt vitae, porttitor nec risus. Mauris faucibus convallis vestibulum. Quisque fringilla non tortor in euismod. Fusce laoreet sapien nec auctor convallis. <br>
    <br>Sed accumsan tortor eu eros pellentesque pulvinar hendrerit vitae nibh. In quis hendrerit eros. Nulla id erat in eros congue maximus. Nam sed lacus vel purus porttitor ultrices. Suspendisse potenti. Fusce sed lorem elementum, accumsan turpis eu, sagittis sapien. Nunc non lorem vitae quam pharetra placerat. Praesent tristique odio non metus lacinia rhoncus.</p>
  </div>
  
  <div id="tabs-4">
        <p><strong>Tab 4</strong><br>
    <br>Integer at blandit leo, sed rhoncus ex. Nulla facilisi. Aliquam fermentum feugiat velit ac feugiat. Praesent a orci ut neque luctus faucibus. Sed pulvinar in tortor eget scelerisque. Sed elementum enim non fringilla placerat. Mauris pulvinar, velit nec ullamcorper varius, turpis leo gravida mi, placerat vehicula urna erat eu metus. Suspendisse lacus neque, tempor et eleifend in, egestas vestibulum enim. Nam commodo mollis tortor non accumsan. Maecenas fringilla ornare mollis.<br>
    <br>
<strong>Nulla at scelerisque nunc.</strong> Aliquam sit amet mi libero. Nulla odio tortor, convallis in mattis vel, porttitor vitae velit. Vestibulum auctor diam nec aliquam iaculis. In nec sapien egestas, tincidunt diam non, gravida lacus. Nullam luctus hendrerit mollis. Duis bibendum, velit sed vulputate hendrerit, sapien eros pharetra metus, nec volutpat arcu felis eu risus. Proin condimentum, odio eu vestibulum fringilla, ex arcu iaculis massa, sagittis dignissim odio tortor non ex. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Morbi porta ullamcorper erat et rhoncus. Cras rutrum nisl vel velit consequat, quis malesuada orci suscipit. Vestibulum in consequat lacus. <br>
<br>Pellentesque sollicitudin aliquet ultrices. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Etiam viverra facilisis felis. Donec lobortis, risus vel venenatis ultrices, magna nulla egestas magna, eu sodales arcu nibh eu lorem.</p>
  </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: The CMS adds the script. Its needed to display certain functions of the CMS

Comment: So how do I prevent this script from effecting my coding?

Comment: You need to change the name of your classes or scope it.

Comment: which of my class names are defined in the jquery-ui-1.8.9.custom.css script? For example is the .tabs class conflicting with that stylesheet? Also what do you mean by scoping?